# 502 - failed_to_connect_to_backend from LB on HEALTHY target group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I have some global Load balancer on the GCP. This balancer should send requests to the instance group with two back services.
And when I try to send some requests, I randomly get 502 errors `failed_to_connect_to_backend` from my load balancer.

I can get a successful answer seven times, one by one, and then 2-3 times 502 error for the same request.

In the
[Monitoring Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkVGK.png) I see this - my both services are healthy.
The [Instanse groups overwiev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrSri.png) shows 100% healthy status too.

URL map rules is default [default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX55M.png)
I also don`t see [any problems with resource consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao9Xs.png)

And, unfortunately, I couldn't get any logs from the back-end side for the 502 errors, have only logs from the Load Balancer

Comment: The backends will have logs as well unless logging is not configured. Locate or solve that problem as a first step in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of coffee and liters of manuals (I'm not very well versed in GCP yet) the "problem" is solved - at some point I noticed that the execution time of all failed requests is ~ 9 seconds.
Therefore, I tried to search for results with similar symptoms, as a result I found a answer on the [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/7ETsl0YH1iQ/m/vMgs7_TvAwAJ)

In my case - we have trobles with port mapping(was used two ports in mapping - like 80, 6000. And 80 - was not listening from the backend side)
After removing closed - 502s gone away.

Answer (score 0):

If port 80 was not allowed on the firewall rule applied on the backend instances?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).